# Cannot apply typescript type to a derived svelte store

Tags: typescript, svelte, svelte-store

I have a working dervived store called **selectedDocument** in svelte. I am getting the following TS linting error when I attempt to add the correct type to it. (And the intellisense is not working)

## TS Linting errors

### on  the definition of the **selectedDocument** store

```
Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.ts(2558)
```

## on ([$selectedDocId, $userDocuments])

```
Type '{ view_id: never; user_id: never; doc_id: never; user_name: never; user_avatar: never; cardMap: never; cards: never; }' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)
```

## THE CODE

The store works and the type works with other similar data

### Interfaces

```
export interface MainView {
  view_id: string;
  user_id: string;
  doc_id: string;
  user_name: string;
  user_avatar: string;
  cardMap: CardMap;
  cards: {
    [key: string]: Card;
  };
}
export interface Document {
    doc_id: string;
    createDate: Date;
    createdBy: string;
    title: string;
  }
```

### Stores

```
const userDocuments = writable<Document[]>(); 

const selectedDocId = writable<string>(""); // Selected doucment Id

const selectedDocument = derived<Document>(
  [selectedDocId, userDocuments],
  ([$selectedDocId, $userDocuments]) =>
    getObjByIdReturnOneObj($userDocuments, $selectedDocId, "doc_id")
);
```

The function getObjByIdReturnOneObj takes in the array of documents and returns a single object (not in an array)

```
export interface MainView {
  view_id: string;
  user_id: string;
  doc_id: string;
  user_name: string;
  user_avatar: string;
  cardMap: CardMap;
  cards: {
    [key: string]: Card;
  };
}
export interface Document {
    doc_id: string;
    createDate: Date;
    createdBy: string;
    title: string;
  }
```

### Stores

```
const userDocuments = writable<Document[]>(); 

const selectedDocId = writable<string>(""); // Selected doucment Id

const selectedDocument = derived<Document>(
  [selectedDocId, userDocuments],
  ([$selectedDocId, $userDocuments]) =>
    getObjByIdReturnOneObj($userDocuments, $selectedDocId, "doc_id")
);
```

The function getObjByIdReturnOneObj takes in the array of documents and returns a single object (not in an array)

Comment: Could you also provide the typing of `getObjByIdReturnOneObj` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the type of `derived`, you will see that it has two type arguments. This is its simplest signature:

```js
export declare function derived<S extends Stores, T>(
  stores: S,
  fn: (values: StoresValues<S>) => T
): Readable<T>;
```

Currently you cannot only specify some of the type arguments, it is all or nothing. Generally, I would recommend **not** specifying the arguments when they can be derived automatically; it mostly just adds unnecessary noise.

In this case the second argument has to have the return type of `getObjByIdReturnOneObj` if you specify the types.

The first one also has to be adjusted to include at least `Readable` as `Stores` is defined as:

```js
declare type Stores =
  Readable<any> |
  [Readable<any>, ...Array<Readable<any>>] |
  Array<Readable<any>>;
```

---

When setting the types you can also use `typeof` to derive types from the existing stores and the function:

```js
const selectedDocument = derived<
    [typeof selectedDocId, typeof userDocuments],
    ReturnType<typeof getObjByIdReturnOneObj>
>(...)
```

Or manually something like:

```js
const selectedDocument = derived<
    [Readable<string>, Readable<Document[]>],
    Document // Based on type specified in question
>(...)
```

Comment: Thats great! I appreciate the thorough answer

Comment: Thanks, though the example could have been simpler to understand using one store dependency, like:

const originalStore = writable<ObjType[]>([]);
const derivedStore = derived<typeof originalStore, ObjType[]>(originalStore, $originalStore => …

But I get use just responded to this specifice usecase...